# Jquery array toggle value is not woking properly

Tags: jquery, arrays

In my check box I am adding a class to element, at the same time I am pushing the value to the array. When the  user clicks  the element again,I am removing the class name and  the value from the array.I have used the following function:

```
var sv = [];

    $(userLocales).click(function(){

                    $(this).parent().toggleClass("red");
                    var elementValue = $(this).val();

                    if($.inArray(elementValue, sv) === -1 ){
                        sv.push(elementValue)
                        console.log("add");//works
                    } else{
                         $.grep(sv, function (value) {
                            return value != elementValue;
                        });
                         console.log("remove");//works..
                    }

                    console.log(sv);//always getting the value
                })
```

What is the issue ?Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May be the problem is in `else` block. From `$.grep` description: "Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected."

Comment: then is there any way to remove for my toggle senario..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still looking for jQuery solution so here it is , just update your `else` block:

```
sv = $.grep(sv, function (value) {
   return value != elementValue;
});
```

(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PKCES/)

jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Answer (score 1):

In your `else` clause do this

```
var index = sv.indexOf(elementValue);
sv.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: will this work, the value exist in any of the index or only work on index no.1..?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
} else{
    sv.splice( $.inArray(elementValue, sv), 1 );
    console.log("remove");//works..
}
...
```